# Cordova: Not able to copy file on Android using Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, webkit, asp.net-web-api

Somehow I keep getting an "error code 5" when trying to set the following right.
What I want to do, is copy an existing file from the assets in android to an accessible spot on the android device to be able to share it across other apps (like mail).

Here is my code example:

```
    window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
    var storagefolder = cordova.file.dataDirectory;
    var storagefolderpointer;
    console.log("storage folder: " + storagefolder);

    // Check for support.
    if (window.requestFileSystem) {
        console.log("filesystem beschikbaar");
        var getFSfail = function () {
            console.log('Could not open filesystem');
        };
        var getFSsuccess = function(fs) {

            var getDIRsuccess = function (dir) {
                    console.debug('Got dirhandle');
                    cachedir = dir;
                    fileurl  = fs.root.fullPath + '/' + storagefolder;
                    storagefolderpointer = dir;
            };
            var getDIRfail = function () {
                console.log('Could not open directory');
            };

            console.debug('Got fshandle');
            FS = fs;
            FS.root.getDirectory(storagefolder, {create:true,exclusive:false}, getDIRsuccess, getDIRfail);
        };
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, getFSsuccess, getFSfail);

        setTimeout(function() {

            console.log("directory beschikbaar");
            var suc = function(entry){
                var goe = function(){
                    console.log("copy success");
                };
                var fou = function(){
                    console.log("copy NOT NOT success");
                };
                entry.copyTo(storagefolder, "vcard.vcf", goe, fou);
            };
            var fai = function(e){
                console.log("fail getFile: " + e.code);
            };
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(storagefolderpointer + "www/visitekaart/vcard.vcf", suc, fai);

        }, 1000);

    } else {
        console.log("filesystem NOT NOT NOT available");
    }
```

Comment: Is related to [this issue](https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova/issues/506)? See the 10th comment

Comment: Have you tried using filechooser? https://github.com/MaginSoft/MFileChooser

Comment: The error is an `ENCODING_ERR` as by the docs https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file, please state it in the question it might be relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you use cordovaFile plugin instead?,you can use blob to read the content of your files than write a new one on android sdcard using cordovaFile plugin

```
$cordovaFile.writeFile('appdata/file.txt', blob, 0).then(function(fileEntry) {
    //success
}, function(err) {
    //err
}
```